# How to prove that $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} z^k(1-z)^{n-k} (k-nz)^2 = nz(1-z)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, binomial-theorem

for a practice exercise I have to prove that
$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} z^k(1-z)^{n-k} (k-nz)^2 = nz(1-z)$
using the binomial theorem, but I can't work it out.
I know obviously that $1 = (z+(1-z))^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} z^k(1-z)^{n-k}$ but I don't know how to work the $(k-nz)^2$ in there.

Comment: Try expanding $(k-nz)^2$ and split the sum in 3 sums

Comment: I tried that but I can't work out the sum that has $k^2$ in it

Comment: That $k^2$ can be worked out by simplifying it with the binomial coefficient

Comment: As a hint, note that $$(k-nz)^2 = k(k-1) + (1-2nz)k + n^2z^2$$ and that $$k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}\qquad\text{and}\qquad k(k-1)\binom{n}{k}=n(n-1)\binom{n-2}{k-2}.$$

Comment: I have solved it, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof of a more general identity.

Let $n$ be a non-negative integer, and consider the identity

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n}{k}z^k w^{n-k} e^{(kw - (n-k)z)s} = (z e^{ws} + w e^{-zs})^n $$

in three variables $z$, $w$, and $s$, which is a consequence of the binomial theorem. Differentiating both sides with respect $s$, we get

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n}{k}z^k w^{n-k} (kw - (n-k)z) e^{(kw - (n-k)z)s} = n zw (e^{ws} - e^{-zs}) (z e^{ws} + w e^{-zs})^{n-1}. $$

Differentiating both sides with respect $s$ again,

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n}{k}z^k w^{n-k} (kw - (n-k)z)^2 e^{(kw - (n-k)z)s} \\
&\quad = n zw (w e^{ws} + z e^{-zs}) (z e^{ws} + w e^{-zs})^{n-1} \\
&\qquad + n(n-1) z^2w^2 (e^{ws} - e^{-zs})^2 (z e^{ws} + w e^{-zs})^{n-2}.
\end{align*}

Plugging $s = 0$ to both sides, we get

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n}{k}z^k w^{n-k} (kw - (n-k)z)^2
= n zw (z + w)^n. $$

If $w = 1-z$, then this identity reduces to the one asked by OP.